# SharePoint List View Search Box Prompt for Credentials for Anonymous Users

Tags: sharepoint-server, list-view, anonymous-authentication

I have a page where I put a SharePoint List View. The list view has search box enabled and it is working perfectly for logged in users.

However, when I tried to use the search box as an anonymous user, after I typed the search term and hit Enter, it prompted me with a Login Window.

Is this a behavior by design? Or is there something I could do to solve this issue? (Of course I have already set up the anonymous access for my site)

Answer (score 2):

I have reproduced this issue.

To resolve this issue, you should deactivate ‘**Limit-access user permission lockdown mode**’ site collection feature (Site Settings > Site collection features).

[image]

Comment: I see.. But in my site I need the SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure, which needs Limit-Access User Permission Lockdown Mode to be activated (my site has workflows and use a lot of Image Rendition feature). But I am still confused because this article https://support.office.com/en-us/article/enable-or-disable-site-collection-features-a2f2a5c2-093d-4897-8b7f-37f86d83df04 stated that the Limit-Access user permission lockdown mode does not have impact to other features while this article https://support.microsoft.com/en-za/kb/3039997 stated that it is needed.